# Using Ajax, how can I populate a div with Database Content from a form select?

Tags: forms, ajax

This is what I have so far. I can populate the select field just fine, however when another option is selected I can not get the data to populate in the ajax callback div.

```
function product_comparison_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['design_product_comparison'] = array(
    'title'            => t('Product Comparison'),
    'menu_name' => 'menu-main-menu',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array('product_comparison_form'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/*
* Display output
*/
function product_comparison_form($form, &$form_state) {

  //Query DB for Rows
$query = db_select('product_comparison');
$query->fields('product_comparison', array('id', 'OtherCombo',));
$query->condition('DropdownCategory', 'Exit Devices');
$query->orderBy('OtherCombo', 'ASC');
$results = $query->execute();

    //define rows
$options = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $options[$result->id] = $result->OtherCombo;
}

$form['Exit Devices']['OtherCombo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Exit Devices'),
    '#options' => $options, 
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'product_comparison_ajax_wrapper',
      'callback' => 'product_comparison_form_ajax'
    ),    
);

$form['results'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="product_comparison_ajax_wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
 );

 // If the form has been submitted, build up your results and display them
 if (isset($form_state['Exit Devices']['OtherCombo'])) {
   $row = db_select('product_comparison')
     ->fields('product_comparison', array('DesignHardware', 'DesignImg','DesignURL'))
 ->condition('OtherCombo', $form_state['Exit Devices']['OtherCombo'])
     ->execute();

   $header = array();

   $form['results']['#markup'] = theme('table', array('header' => $header,'rows' => $rows));
  }
  else {
    $form['results']['#markup'] = '<p>The results will appear here when you change the dropdown option.</p>';
  }

 return $form;
}

function product_comparison_form_ajax($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['results'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to populate data in the ajax callback `product_comparison_form_ajax` and then return `$form['results']`.

Your code should be as the following:

**Product comparison form**

```
function product_comparison_form($form, &$form_state) {

  //Query DB for Rows
  $query = db_select('product_comparison');
  $query->fields('product_comparison', array('id', 'OtherCombo',));
  $query->condition('DropdownCategory', 'Exit Devices');
  $query->orderBy('OtherCombo', 'ASC');
  $results = $query->execute();

  //define rows
  $options = array();
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $options[$result->id] = $result->OtherCombo;
  }

  $form['Exit Devices']['OtherCombo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Exit Devices'),
    '#options' => $options, 
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'product_comparison_ajax_wrapper',
      'callback' => 'product_comparison_form_ajax'
    ),    
  );

  // removed result condition

  $form['results'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="product_comparison_ajax_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#markup' => '<p>The results will appear here when you change the dropdown option.</p>',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

**Product comparison ajax callback**

```
function product_comparison_form_ajax(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['Exit Devices']['OtherCombo'])) {
    $row = db_select('product_comparison')
      ->fields('product_comparison', array('DesignHardware', 'DesignImg','DesignURL'))
      ->condition('OtherCombo', $form_state['Exit Devices']['OtherCombo'])
     ->execute();

    $header = array(
      array('data' => 'Design Hardware'),
      array('data' => 'Design Img'),
      array('data' => 'Design URL'),
    );

    $rows = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
      $rows[] = array('data' => (array) $row);
    }

    // assign result to markup
    $form['results']['#markup'] = theme('table',array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

  }

  return $form['results'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

3 things to commment:

1. The variable `$row` is not the same the variable `$rows` that you pass in the theme function. I think it's a misspelling error.
2. Your `$header` variable is empty when you pass to theme table. I am not sure if it's necessary to send it with data.
3. To verify the table is empty, i've added a new variable called `empty` to your theme variables. The documentation fo theme_table() in theme.inc says:

> empty: The message to display in an extra row if table does not have any
>        rows.

I've changed 2 things in the next piece of code:

```
// If the form has been submitted, build up your results and display them
if (isset($form_state['Exit Devices']['OtherCombo'])) {
  $rows = db_select('product_comparison')
  ->fields('product_comparison', 
    array('DesignHardware','DesignImg','DesignURL'))
  ->condition('OtherCombo', $form_state['Exit Devices']['OtherCombo'])
  ->execute();

  $header = array();

  $form['results']['#markup'] = theme('table',
   array('header' => $header,'rows'=> $rows, 'empty' => 'empty table'));
  }else{
  $form['results']['#markup'] = '<p>The results will appear here when you  change the dropdown option.</p>';
```

}

Comment: Thanks Aboodred1 and Rufein using what you guys provided I was able to get this working. I am new to this forum and I am loving it so far, is there anything I can do to give you guys credit for this.

Comment: You are welcome @CodeWeaver. I recommend you to read the [faqs](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq) to understand how it works :)